# elasticsearch php api with multiple hosts

Tags: php, azure, elasticsearch

I followed this link to create an elasticsearch 2 nodes cluster on Azure:
[this link](http://thomasardal.com/running-elasticsearch-in-a-cluster-on-azure/)

the installation and configuring went good.

When i started to check the cluster i found a strange behaviour from the php client.

I declared 2 hosts in the client:

```
$ELSEARCH_SERVER = array("dns1:9200","dns2:9200");
$params = array();
$params['hosts'] = $ELSEARCH_SERVER;
$dstEl = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```

the excpected behaviour is that it will try to insert the documents to "dns1" and if it fails it will **automatically** change to "dns2".
but, for some reason when one of the servers is down on insertion the php client throws an exception that it couldn't connect to host and only.

Is there any way to cause the client automatically choose an online server?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Solution: After debugging the the elasticsearch php client I found a retry mechansim that allows the client to jump to the next server from the pool if the previous is down.
**this mechanism is disabled by default**

to enable this mechanism you need to initialize the Client with a parameter called retries:

```
$params = array();
$params['hosts'] = $ELSEARCH_SERVER;    
$params['retries'] = count($ELSEARCH_SERVER);
$dstEl = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```

Hope it will help you guys

Comment: Hmm, what version of the client are you using? You shouldn't need to modify the `retries` parameter by default...sounds like buggy behavior. Can you open a ticket at the Github repo and I'll look into it?